# How do I restart mysql and where is my.cnf file

Tags: mysql

I am using a Mac OS X Snow Leopard Apple computer.

I installed MySQL on my machine using instructions mentioned [here](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard). Everything works great. However I have two questions.

1. Where is `my.cnf` file? I searched the whole file system and result is empty. Is it possible that there is no `my.cnf` and MySQL works with default values. If yes then probably I should create `my.cnf` at `/etc/mysql`. Is that right?
2. How do I restart the MySQL server ? I know it gets started when I restart my machine. Here is what plist looks like. `mysqld_safe` does not let me restart server.

   KeepAlive
       
       Label
       com.mysql.mysqld
       Program
       /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
       RunAtLoad
       
       UserName
       mysql
       WorkingDirectory
       /usr/local/mysql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the example my.cnf that comes with mysql:

```
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is /usr/local/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
```

On my OS X 10.4 instance, my.cnf is at /etc/my.cnf.

To restart mysql, use mysqladmin to shut it down and then start it up again with mysqld_safe:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe &
```

Answer (score 3):

1. It possible it doesn't exist. You can create one in `/etc/my.cnf` or in your `datadir` (usually `/var/lib/mysql` or `/usr/local/var`).
2. I usually use `mysqladmin shutdown` (might need a `-p` if you have a password set) and then a `sudo mysqld_safe &` to start it up.

Comment: The file, per se, does not exist.  Instead, in /usr/local/mysql-5* for 64 bit MAC OS X, look in /support-files and you will see: my-small.cnf, my-medium.cnf, mylarge.cnf and my-huge.cnf. Choose one of these, copy it into my.cnf, configure and go.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us what OS you're on, but the defaults on Debian Linux are:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

for restart, and the `my.cnf` file is located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: I am using snow leopard mac. Sorry I should have mentioned.